# Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync runs at one place but it doesn't in another place

Tags: reactjs, outlook, dialog, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing a Microsoft Outlook add-in, and I'm facing the following issue:

I want to send data from dialog box (child) to taskpane (parent) and close the dialoge box based on that message. I am using **Office.context.ui.messageParent** for passing message from dialog box to the task pane. The issue I am facing is that I am able to send data only one time in the dialoge box to parent. I am trying to send it from another place , the same function dosn't work.

I have added my code snippet below:

**Task pane code were I open the dialog box**

```
const dialogOptions = {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  requireHTTPS: true,
};
const messageToDialog = JSON.stringify({
  companySsoEmail: localStorage.getItem('companySsoEmail'),
  companySsoId: companyDomainId,
  isDialog: localStorage.getItem('isDialog'),
});

Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(popupUrl, dialogOptions, (result) => {
  const dialog = result.value;
  dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, (arg) => {
    if (arg.message === 'IAmReady') {
      dialog.messageChild(messageToDialog);
    }

    if (arg.message === 'SignInSuccessful') {
      console.log('message: ', arg.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
      dialog.close();
    }
  });
});
```

**Dialog box code where child message is passed to the task pane**

```
const SsoLoginTwo = () => {
```

This code works

```
  Office.initialize = async () => {
    Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DialogParentMessageReceived, (args) => {
      console.log(args.message);
      localStorage.setItem('parentData', args.message);
    });
    Office.context.ui.messageParent('IAmReady');
  };
```

////////////////////

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const getParams = (param) => urlSearchParams.get(param);
    const state = getParams('state');
    if (state) {
      setLocalStorageValue('state', state);
    }
    const getSAMLUrl = () => {
      const base = String(getParams('base_url'));
      const temporary = base.split('?SAMLRequest=');
      const url = `${temporary[0]}?SAMLRequest=${encodeURIComponent(
        temporary[1],
      )}`;
      return url;
    };
    const baseCheck = () => (getParams('scope') !== 'null' && getParams('client_id') !== 'null'
      ? getParams('base_url')
      : getSAMLUrl());

    const clientCheck = () => (getParams('scope') !== 'null' && getParams('client_id') !== 'null'
      ? `&client_id=${getParams('client_id')}&scope=${getParams(
        'scope',
      )}&prompt=${getParams('prompt')}`
      : '');
    window.location.href = `${baseCheck()}${clientCheck()}&redirect_uri=${getParams(
      'redirect_uri',
    )}`;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Spinner />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Callback url code after user signs in**

```
   /* global Office, */
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/office-js-helpers';
import * as msTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';
import { connect, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import Spinner from '../../common/spinner';
import { API_URL_CALLBACK } from '../../../Configurations';
import isExpiredToken from '../../../utils/isExpiredToken';
import {
  currentAppName,
  getLocalStorageValue,
  isTeamsApp,
} from '../../../utils/CommonUtils';
import Loader from '../../common/Loader';

const CallBackUrl = (props) => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const loginDetail = useSelector((state) => state.ssoLogin.loginData);
  const login = useSelector((state) => state.ssoLogin);
  const state1 = useSelector((state) => console.log('state; ', state));
  console.log('data-two', loginDetail, login, state1);
  const myParam = urlParams.get('code');
  const isTeamsDialog = getLocalStorageValue('isTeamsDialog') === 'true';

  Office.initialize = async () => {
    await Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DialogParentMessageReceived,
      (args) => {
      console.log(args.message);
      localStorage.setItem('parentData', args.message);
    });
    Office.context.ui.messageParent('SignInSuccessful');
  };

  if (getLocalStorageValue('isDialog') === 'true') {
    console.log('location: ', window.location.href);
    Dialog.close(window.location.href);
    localStorage.removeItem('isDialog');
  } else if (isTeamsDialog || isTeamsApp()) {
    localStorage.removeItem('isTeamsDialog');
    msTeams.initialize();
    localStorage.removeItem('auth.error');
    if (myParam) {
      const data = { code: myParam };
      msTeams.authentication.notifySuccess(data);
    } else {
      msTeams.authentication.notifyFailure({ error: 'something went wrong' });
    }
  } else {
    const userData = {
      code: myParam,
      company_id: getLocalStorageValue('companySsoId'),
      email: getLocalStorageValue('companySsoEmail'),
      appName: currentAppName(),
    };

    const actionStates = {};

    useEffect(() => {
      const { history } = props;
      console.log('history is not empty', history);
      isExpiredToken(
        userData,
        API_URL_CALLBACK,
        history,
        actionStates,
        null,
        null,
        null,
      );
    }, [myParam]);
  }

  return (
    <main id="main">
      {isTeamsDialog ? <Loader /> : <Spinner key="Spinner" />}
    </main>
  );
};

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  status: state.auth.status,
  name: state.auth.name,
  token: state.auth.token,
});

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, {})(withRouter(CallBackUrl));
```

In the above code the parent does't receive the **SignInSuccessful** message. My code doesn't enter the  await Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync block.

Comment: I have jsut figured out thaat my dialog box and task pane are running in different domains. Therefore I tried Office.context.ui.messageParent(data, { targetOrigin: '*' }); but still message is not sent to the task pane.

Comment: How is the CallBackUrl component loaded? It's possible that office.initialize is set too late.